# Does Visual Studio Services provide a full workflow for CI/CD of web applications?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-app-center

I read about [Microsoft Visual Studio App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/), but it seems to only apply to developing native apps.

I need to realize a Selenium-based CI/CD workflow, like this:

1. Programmers develop a web application locally, pushing their changes to a local GitLab repository.
2. The on-premise "service" watches the GitLab repository for changes. If changes have been detected, then:

   1. Pull project.
   2. Compile project in Release configuration.
   3. Run NodeJS unit tests and validate results.
   4. Deploy to on-premise test site.
   5. Using local (non-public) URLs, run Selenium web tests in parallel on different devices (e.g. Windows 10 desktops, tablets and smartphones; Apple tablets and smartphones; Android tablets and smartphones) with different browsers (i.e. Edge, FireFox, Chrome, Internet Explorer) and validate results.

      Using "local" URLs stands for something similar to [BrowserStack Local](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing).

      This includes the ability to take screenshots and to compare them to reference screenshots of a previous test on the same device/browser.
   6. Show test results of all the tests.
   7. If all the tests have run successfully,

      1. Request confirmation to deploy to production site.
      2. Deploy to production site.

Does Microsoft offer on-premise services for this? Which are they?

Answer (score 2):

You can still get [TFS](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/) from Microsoft as an On-premise variant of [VSTS](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/). Both have the same codebase, but the SaaS variant is released more often (every three weeks!).

VSTS/TFS can handle Git repositories out of the box, with all steps you described. Even uploading a new software version to all the stores :-)

Comment: Sounds great. My customer's policies require on-premise. I'm currently using Ranorex for recording/playing-back tests. What would be the TFS alternative? Would you mind providing hyperlinks to corresponding topics for the above mentioned topics so I can quickly get into it? Do all the devices served at the Microsoft cloud (step 5.2) provide Developer Tools?

Comment: I don't know Ranorex (looks like most other tools for this). If you can start it from the commandline, you can run it from TFS (software needs to be deployed on an agent).

Comment: You could start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/?view=vsts to learn more about TFS.